# BigQuery UDF Internal Error

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, udf

We had a simple UDF in BigQuery that somehow throws an error that keeps returning

```
Query Failed
Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
```

The query was simply trying to use UDF to perform a SHA256.

```
SELECT
  input AS title,
  input_sha256 AS title_sha256
FROM
  SHA256(
      SELECT
        title AS input
      FROM
        [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.stories]
      GROUP BY
        input 
  )
LIMIT
  1000
```

The in-line UDF is pasted below. However I can not post the full UDF as StackOverflow complaints too much code in the post. The full UDF can be seen [this gist](https://gist.github.com/PaulLiang1/bd3d250043fbcab8af5f).

```
function sha256(row, emit) {
  emit(
      {
        input: row.input,
        input_sha256: CryptoJS.SHA256(row.input).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
      }
  );
}

bigquery.defineFunction(
  'SHA256',                           // Name of the function exported to SQL
  ['input'],                    // Names of input columns
  [
      {'name': 'input', 'type': 'string'},
      {'name': 'input_sha256', 'type': 'string'}
  ],
  sha256                       // Reference to JavaScript UDF
);
```

Not sure if it helps, but the Job-ID is

```
bigquery:bquijob_7fd3b51c_153c058dc7c
```

Looks like there is a similar issue at:

```
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=478
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - this is an issue related to memory allocation that I uncovered via my own testing and fixed today, but it will take a little while to flow out to production.

Slightly longer answer - we just rolled out a fix today for an issue where users who were having "out of memory" issues when scaling up their UDFs over larger number of rows, even though the UDF would succeed on smaller numbers of rows.  The queries that were hitting that condition are now running fine on our internal / test trees.  However, since public BigQuery hosts have much higher traffic loads, the JavaScript engine that executes the UDFs (V8) behaves somewhat differently in production than it does in internal trees.  Specifically, there's a new memory allocation error that some of the previously OOMing jobs are now hitting that we couldn't observe until the queries ran on a fully-loaded tree.

It's a minor error with a quick fix, but we'd ideally let it flow through our regular testing and QA cycle.  This should put the fix in production in about a week, assuming nothing else goes wrong with the candidate.  Would that be acceptable for you?

Comment: is it possible for you to run this exactly query and confirm it is working in your internal env? or we should wait when this fix it will hit public?

Comment: we are running sha256 similar to example in question and now it works only in batches of around 40 rows - will it work for all around 1.8M rows as it is in above example?

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround. We have some production batch job that relies on UDF, but I guess we will need to find a work around

Comment: I've confirmed with the engineers driving our deployment - target date for the 2nd fix landing is end of this week.  I can definitely try this query on the internal tree later this afternoon.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - have you got a job id that I can use to repro your 1.8MM query ?

Comment: @thomaspark - I pasted query to answer. it works with LIMIT 40. it fails with rows count more than 45. Table in example from question has 1.8MM

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant the query works on the internal trees against the full 1.8 MM rows.  Interestingly, if I run this JS enough times *without* the bugfix we're rolling out later this week, I can repro the memory allocation error on internal trees.  So I'm very confident that your query will work after this week's update is live  :)

Comment: perfect. thank you for test and update - cc @PaulLeung

Comment: @PaulLeung - the fix has been deployed; your query now works  :)  FYI, it would be slightly more performant to put the LIMIT in the nested subquery than to limit the results after running all of the rows through the JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

i am re-using answer box to provide full query text. it works if uncomment LIMIT 40

```
SELECT input, input_sha256 FROM JS(
(
  SELECT title AS input
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.stories]
  GROUP BY input
  //LIMIT 40 
),
input,
"[ {'name': 'input', 'type': 'string'}, {'name': 'input_sha256', 'type': 'string'} ] ",

"function(row, emit) { 
  var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(h,s){var f={},g=f.lib={},q=function(){},m=g.Base={extend:function(a){q.prototype=this;var c=new q;a&&c.mixIn(a);c.hasOwnProperty('init')||(c.init=function(){c.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)});c.init.prototype=c;c.$super=this;return c},create:function(){var a=this.extend();a.init.apply(a,arguments);return a},init:function(){},mixIn:function(a){for(var c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(this[c]=a[c]);a.hasOwnProperty('toString')&&(this.toString=a.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}}, r=g.WordArray=m.extend({init:function(a,c){a=this.words=a||[];this.sigBytes=c!=s?c:4*a.length},toString:function(a){return(a||k).stringify(this)},concat:function(a){var c=this.words,d=a.words,b=this.sigBytes;a=a.sigBytes;this.clamp();if(b%4)for(var e=0;e<a;e++)c[b+e>>>2]|=(d[e>>>2]>>>24-8*(e%4)&255)<<24-8*((b+e)%4);else if(65535<d.length)for(e=0;e<a;e+=4)c[b+e>>>2]=d[e>>>2];else c.push.apply(c,d);this.sigBytes+=a;return this},clamp:function(){var a=this.words,c=this.sigBytes;a[c>>>2]&=4294967295<< 32-8*(c%4);a.length=h.ceil(c/4)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this);a.words=this.words.slice(0);return a},random:function(a){for(var c=[],d=0;d<a;d+=4)c.push(4294967296*h.random()|0);return new r.init(c,a)}}),l=f.enc={},k=l.Hex={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++){var e=c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255;d.push((e>>>4).toString(16));d.push((e&15).toString(16))}return d.join('')},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b+=2)d[b>>>3]|=parseInt(a.substr(b, 2),16)<<24-4*(b%8);return new r.init(d,c/2)}},n=l.Latin1={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++)d.push(String.fromCharCode(c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255));return d.join('')},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b++)d[b>>>2]|=(a.charCodeAt(b)&255)<<24-8*(b%4);return new r.init(d,c)}},j=l.Utf8={stringify:function(a){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(n.stringify(a)))}catch(c){throw Error('Malformed UTF-8 data');}},parse:function(a){return n.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(a)))}}, u=g.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=m.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new r.init;this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(a){'string'==typeof a&&(a=j.parse(a));this._data.concat(a);this._nDataBytes+=a.sigBytes},_process:function(a){var c=this._data,d=c.words,b=c.sigBytes,e=this.blockSize,f=b/(4*e),f=a?h.ceil(f):h.max((f|0)-this._minBufferSize,0);a=f*e;b=h.min(4*a,b);if(a){for(var g=0;g<a;g+=e)this._doProcessBlock(d,g);g=d.splice(0,a);c.sigBytes-=b}return new r.init(g,b)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this); a._data=this._data.clone();return a},_minBufferSize:0});g.Hasher=u.extend({cfg:m.extend(),init:function(a){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(a);this.reset()},reset:function(){u.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},update:function(a){this._append(a);this._process();return this},finalize:function(a){a&&this._append(a);return this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new a.init(d)).finalize(c)}},_createHmacHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new t.HMAC.init(a, d)).finalize(c)}}});var t=f.algo={};return f}(Math); 
  (function(h){for(var s=CryptoJS,f=s.lib,g=f.WordArray,q=f.Hasher,f=s.algo,m=[],r=[],l=function(a){return 4294967296*(a-(a|0))|0},k=2,n=0;64>n;){var j;a:{j=k;for(var u=h.sqrt(j),t=2;t<=u;t++)if(!(j%t)){j=!1;break a}j=!0}j&&(8>n&&(m[n]=l(h.pow(k,0.5))),r[n]=l(h.pow(k,1/3)),n++);k++}var a=[],f=f.SHA256=q.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new g.init(m.slice(0))},_doProcessBlock:function(c,d){for(var b=this._hash.words,e=b[0],f=b[1],g=b[2],j=b[3],h=b[4],m=b[5],n=b[6],q=b[7],p=0;64>p;p++){if(16>p)a[p]= c[d+p]|0;else{var k=a[p-15],l=a[p-2];a[p]=((k<<25|k>>>7)^(k<<14|k>>>18)^k>>>3)+a[p-7]+((l<<15|l>>>17)^(l<<13|l>>>19)^l>>>10)+a[p-16]}k=q+((h<<26|h>>>6)^(h<<21|h>>>11)^(h<<7|h>>>25))+(h&m^~h&n)+r[p]+a[p];l=((e<<30|e>>>2)^(e<<19|e>>>13)^(e<<10|e>>>22))+(e&f^e&g^f&g);q=n;n=m;m=h;h=j+k|0;j=g;g=f;f=e;e=k+l|0}b[0]=b[0]+e|0;b[1]=b[1]+f|0;b[2]=b[2]+g|0;b[3]=b[3]+j|0;b[4]=b[4]+h|0;b[5]=b[5]+m|0;b[6]=b[6]+n|0;b[7]=b[7]+q|0},_doFinalize:function(){var a=this._data,d=a.words,b=8*this._nDataBytes,e=8*a.sigBytes; d[e>>>5]|=128<<24-e%32;d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+14]=h.floor(b/4294967296);d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+15]=b;a.sigBytes=4*d.length;this._process();return this._hash},clone:function(){var a=q.clone.call(this);a._hash=this._hash.clone();return a}});s.SHA256=q._createHelper(f);s.HmacSHA256=q._createHmacHelper(f)})(Math); 
  (function(){var h=CryptoJS,j=h.lib.WordArray;h.enc.Base64={stringify:function(b){var e=b.words,f=b.sigBytes,c=this._map;b.clamp();b=[];for(var a=0;a<f;a+=3)for(var d=(e[a>>>2]>>>24-8*(a%4)&255)<<16|(e[a+1>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+1)%4)&255)<<8|e[a+2>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+2)%4)&255,g=0;4>g&&a+0.75*g<f;g++)b.push(c.charAt(d>>>6*(3-g)&63));if(e=c.charAt(64))for(;b.length%4;)b.push(e);return b.join('')},parse:function(b){var e=b.length,f=this._map,c=f.charAt(64);c&&(c=b.indexOf(c),-1!=c&&(e=c));for(var c=[],a=0,d=0;d< e;d++)if(d%4){var g=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d-1))<<2*(d%4),h=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d))>>>6-2*(d%4);c[a>>>2]|=(g|h)<<24-8*(a%4);a++}return j.create(c,a)},_map:'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/='}})(); 
  emit( { input: row.input, input_sha256: CryptoJS.SHA256(row.input).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex) } ); 
}" 
)
```

Comment: Mikhail - your query now works as well.  It takes about 5-8 minutes to run on the entire hacker_news.stores table, per my experimentation just now.

Comment: thank you for update! just to be clear - i presented this query as working example of @PaulLeung 's query as he was not able to show it in his question. but this example represented my issue also - so thanks again. i am checking how it runs  now

Comment: btw, billing tier is 41 :o)